# array.indexOf() returns -1 value when both of the values are same

Tags: reactjs

I want the index of that value but it returns -1. **uniqID** is present in array but still it returns -1 value[image]

```
const history = useHistory();
const classes = useStyle();
let uniqID = localStorage.getItem('uniqID')
let students_array_1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('student'))



const editStudent = () =>{


    let student_id = students_array_1.map(student => student.id)
    let index = student_id.indexOf(uniqID) //it returns -1 index when both of the values are same
    console.log(index);

}
```

Comment: `uniqId` is most likely a `string` and not a `number` like your `students_array_1` array is

Comment: o yes thank youuuu

Comment: Adding to what @nbokmans said, you might need to use parseFloat() to convert your string and search in number array

Comment: i am test . `var res = [0.24716322490311127 , 0.7608841088398548]`.and result `res.indexOf(0.24716322490311127)` is `0`.

Comment: Try using `findIndex` method: `student_id.findIndex(id => id == uniqID);`. This will solve the problem even if the types of both ids are different. `indexOf` method uses strict equality comparison (===) which means that the types of ids should be same for it to find the value.